# how can get one foreach loop for multidimensional array key

Tags: php, arrays, xml

```
    <user>
      <name>
         <dob><test>15</test>  </dob>
         <age></age>
    </name>
        <name1><test></test></name1>
    <name2></name2>
    </user>
```

Explain : i have need output like(
    user.name.dob
    user.name.age
    user.name1.test
    user.name2) this.i want use one for each .Can i get by recursion method.if yes that how.please help me out this

Comment: This is an xml file, you can parse it using xml parser.

Comment: do have any example with solution ,Please

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example, you'll want to restructure XML a bit.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<parent><user>
      <name>John</name>
      <dob>1/1/2015</dob>
      <age>12</age>
    </user>
    <user>
      <name>luke</name>
      <dob>2/1/2015</dob>
      <age>21</age>
    </user></parent>');
$base = 0;
foreach ($xml as $user) {
    $base++;
    echo  $base . '.user.' . $user->name . '.' . $user->dob . '.' . $user->age . "\n";
}
```

Link to the manual, http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php.

Comment: Hello, I need a answer  like 
1.user.name.dob 
2.user.name.age
 3.user.name1.test 
4.user.name2
you give value but key and first not able than go second. please give me solution.

Comment: you are did -1 please give me answer

Comment: I'm tempted to just flag your whole post here with that response. Why dont you give me a minute to work with YOUR TERRIBLE XML.

Comment: There's your update, with your XML set up in a way that makes sense.

Comment: hello i think you don't understand my question but you did me down -1 why. what is my question. My question want key not a value. ans like 1.user.name.age and if not able third than answer 2.user.name1

please understand i need this answer for mapping

Comment: You're not trying anything on your own. You have examples here, you have examples in that link, you have examples all over the web. What is your question if that isn't right? Post exactly what you want from your example above.

Comment: @santosh Not my downvote! I hve voted it up. but your question isnt clear.